# Hardhat test error, missing argument in contract constructor

Tags: tokens, hardhat, testing, solidity-0.8.x

okay, I have edited my test file and now I am getting an entirely different error.

ERROR

```
1) BCCasino tests
       "before each" hook for "..should deploy correctly":     
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\BCCasino.test.js:8:63)      
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)
```

BCCasino.test.js

```
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");
const {expect} = require("chai");

describe("BCCasino tests", () => {
    let token20, token721, token1155;
    
beforeEach(async () => {
    const Token20 = await ethers.utils.getAddress(token20.address);
    token20 = await Token20.deploy(1);
    await token20.deployed();

    const Token721 = await ethers.utils.getAddress(token721.address);
    token721 = await Token721.deploy(1);
    await token721.deployed();
    
    
    const Token1155 = await ethers.utils.getAddress(token1155.address);
    token1155 = await Token1155.deploy(1);
    await token1155.deployed();
    
    const TokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(TokenFactory.address);
    casino = await TokenFactory.deploy(1);
    await casino.deployed();
    

});

it("..should deploy correctly", async () => {
    //const parsedABI = JSON.parse("BCCasino");
    [owner, _] = await ethers.getSigners();

    expect(await casino.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
    expect(await casino.token20()).to.equal(token20.address);
    expect(await casino.token721()).to.equal(token721.address);
    expect(await casino.token1155()).to.equal(token1155.address);

    console.log(owner.address);
    console.log(token20.address);
    console.log(token721.address);
    console.log(token1155.address);
    
});
});
```

I have tried to make sure all of my functions have the same number of parameters as the constructor. I have inserted "casino" as a variable and I have removed it.  I am following a Blockchain Council tutorial on building a simple slot machine game and I am getting this error each time I test.  Thank you.

ERROR MESSAGE

```
  1) BCCasino tests
  

         "before each" hook for "..should deploy correctly":
         Error: missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=1, expectedCount=4, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
    js:48:23)
          at Object.next (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
          at C:\Users\smart\WEB3-GAME\Contracts\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:23:71
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
          at __awaiter (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:19:12)
          at ContractFactory.deploy (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:1138:16)
```

BCasino.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

import "./BC1155.sol";
import "./BCNFT.sol";
import "./BCToken.sol";
import "./AccessControl.sol";


contract BCCasino is AccessControl {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    BCCasino public casino;
    BC1155 public token1155;
    BCNFT public token721;
    BCToken public token20;

    Counters.Counter public machineIdCounter;

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public machineToAmount;
    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) public deposits;  //user --> machine -->  amount

    event Deposit(
        address indexed user,
        uint256 indexed machine,
        uint256 amount
    );

    event Reward(
        address indexed user,
        uint256 indexed rewardType,
        uint256 amount
    );

    constructor(address _casino, address _token20, address _token721, address _token1155) {
        
        casino = BCCasino(_casino);
        token20 = BCToken(_token20);
        token721 = BCNFT(_token721);
        token1155 = BC1155(_token1155);
    }
    function addMachine(uint256 amount) external onlyAdmin returns(bool) {
        require(amount > 0, "Invalid amount");
        uint256 machineId = machineIdCounter.current();
        machineToAmount[machineId] = amount;
        machineIdCounter.increment();
        return true;
    }

    function deposit(uint256 machineId) external returns(bool) {
        require(machineId <= machineIdCounter.current(), "Invalid Machine ID");
        address user = msg.sender;
        uint256 amount = machineToAmount[machineId];
        token20.transferFrom(user, address(this), amount);
        deposits[user][machineId] += amount;
        emit Deposit(user, machineId, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function reward(address user, 
                    uint256 amount, 
                    uint256 rewardType, 
                    uint256 machineId
    ) external onlyAdmin returns(bool) {
        require(rewardType < 3, "Invalid reward Type");
        require(
            deposits[user][machineId] >= machineToAmount[machineId],
            "User didn't make a deposit for the game. Invalid request"
        );

        deposits[user][machineId] -= machineToAmount[machineId];

        if(rewardType == 2) {
            token721.mint(user);
            emit Reward(user, 2, 1);
         } else if (rewardType == 1){
            token1155.mint(user, 1);
            emit Reward(user, 1, 1);
         } else {
            token20.mint(user, amount);
            emit Reward(user, 0, amount);
         }

         return true;
        }

    function totalMachine() external view returns(uint256) {
        return machineIdCounter.current();
    }
    }
```

BCCasino.test.js

```
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");
const {expect} = require("chai");

describe("BCCasino tests", () => {
    let casino, token20, token721, token1155;
    
    beforeEach(async () => {
        
    
        
        const TokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCCasino");
        const Token20 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCToken");
        const Token721 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCNFT");
        const Token1155 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BC1155");
        

        casino = await TokenFactory.deploy(1);
        

        token20 = await Token20.deploy(1);
        token721 = await Token721.deploy(1);
        token1155 = await Token1155.deploy(1);
       

        await token20.deployed();
        await token721.deployed();  
        await token1155.deployed();
        await casino.deployed();
    
    });

    it("..should deploy correctly", async () => {
        //const parsedABI = JSON.parse("BCCasino");
        const [owner, token20, token721, token1155] = await ethers.getSigners();

        expect(await casino.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
        expect(await casino.token20()).to.equal(token20.address);
        expect(await casino.token721()).to.equal(token721.address);
        expect(await casino.token1155()).to.equal(token1155.address);

        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the BCCasino constructor you are expecting 4 params:

```
constructor(address _casino, address _token20, address _token721, address _token1155) {..}
```

And in your hardhat test, you are deploying with only one param (1):

```
const TokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCCasino");
casino = await TokenFactory.deploy(1);
```

you should pass 4 addresses to be able to deploy correctly.

```
 casino = await TokenFactory.deploy(address1,address2,address3,address4);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding something here.  I don't know what you mean when you say "address1, address2" apparently.  I am passing the string for the token name as the value but I am getting Invalid address error, but its pointing to "BCToken" as invalid.  ??

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the updated code and subsequent error message.  I think this is what you were mentioning, but I want to be sure.  I am really new to smart contract development so thank you for your patience and help.  I have included the BCToken.sol code since that is the error message information.

ERROR MESSAGE

```
1) BCCasino tests
       "before each" hook for "..should deploy correctly":     
     Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="BCToken", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.7.0)

BCToken.sol

//SPDX-License-Iden8ifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


import "./AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";


contract BCToken is ERC20, AccessControl {

    constructor(uint256 amount) ERC20("BCToken", "BCT") public {}

    function mint(address user, uint amount) 
        external 
        onlyAdmin 
        returns(bool)
    {
        _mint(user, amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

BCCasino.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

import "./BC1155.sol";
import "./BCNFT.sol";
import "./BCToken.sol";
import "./AccessControl.sol";


contract BCCasino is AccessControl {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    BCCasino public casino;
    BC1155 public token1155;
    BCNFT public token721;
    BCToken public token20;

    Counters.Counter public machineIdCounter;

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public machineToAmount;
    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) public deposits;  //user --> machine -->  amount

    event Deposit(
        address indexed user,
        uint256 indexed machine,
        uint256 amount
    );

    event Reward(
        address indexed user,
        uint256 indexed rewardType,
        uint256 amount
    );

    constructor(address _token20, address _token721, address _token1155) {
        
        token20 = BCToken(_token20);
        token721 = BCNFT(_token721);
        token1155 = BC1155(_token1155);
    }
    function addMachine(uint256 amount) external onlyAdmin returns(bool) {
        require(amount > 0, "Invalid amount");
        uint256 machineId = machineIdCounter.current();
        machineToAmount[machineId] = amount;
        machineIdCounter.increment();
        return true;
    }

    function deposit(uint256 machineId) external returns(bool) {
        require(machineId <= machineIdCounter.current(), "Invalid Machine ID");
        address user = msg.sender;
        uint256 amount = machineToAmount[machineId];
        token20.transferFrom(user, address(this), amount);
        deposits[user][machineId] += amount;
        emit Deposit(user, machineId, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function reward(address user, 
                    uint256 amount, 
                    uint256 rewardType, 
                    uint256 machineId
    ) external onlyAdmin returns(bool) {
        require(rewardType < 3, "Invalid reward Type");
        require(
            deposits[user][machineId] >= machineToAmount[machineId],
            "User didn't make a deposit for the game. Invalid request"
        );

        deposits[user][machineId] -= machineToAmount[machineId];

        if(rewardType == 2) {
            token721.mint(user);
            emit Reward(user, 2, 1);
         } else if (rewardType == 1){
            token1155.mint(user, 1);
            emit Reward(user, 1, 1);
         } else {
            token20.mint(user, amount);
            emit Reward(user, 0, amount);
         }

         return true;
        }

    function totalMachine() external view returns(uint256) {
        return machineIdCounter.current();
    }
    }
```

BCCasino.test.js

```
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");
const {expect} = require("chai");

describe("BCCasino tests", () => {
    let token20, token721, token1155;
    
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const Token20 = await ethers.utils.getAddress("BCToken");
        token20 = await Token20.deploy(1);
        

        const Token721 = await ethers.utils.getAddress("BCNFT");
        token721 = await Token721.deploy(1);
        
        
        
        const Token1155 = await ethers.utils.getAddress("BC1155");
        token1155 = await Token1155.deploy(1);
        
        
        const TokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCCasinoi");
        casino = await TokenFactory.deploy(1);
        await casino.deployed(token20.address, token721.address, token1155.address);
        
    
    });

    it("..should deploy correctly", async () => {
        //const parsedABI = JSON.parse("BCCasino");
        [owner, _] = await ethers.getSigners();

        expect(await casino.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
        expect(await casino.token20()).to.equal(token20.address);
        expect(await casino.token721()).to.equal(token721.address);
        expect(await casino.token1155()).to.equal(token1155.address);

        console.log(owner.address);
        console.log(token20.address);
        console.log(token721.address);
        console.log(token1155.address);
        
    });
});
```

In the constructor of the BCCaasino, you are expecting as a first parameter the _casino which is the address of the BCCasino contract when deployed.

I would then change in your contract `_casino` through `address(this)` and then in the constructor:

```
constructor(address _token20, address _token721, address _token1155) {..}
```

And then change your test script to:

```
 const TokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCCasino");
 const Token20 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCToken");
 const Token721 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCNFT");
 const Token1155 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BC1155");
        

   
   token20 = await Token20.deploy(1);
   token721 = await Token721.deploy(1);
   token1155 = await Token1155.deploy(1);
       

   await token20.deployed();
   await token721.deployed();  
   await token1155.deployed();



  await casino.deployed(token20.address,token721.address,token1155.address);
```

you are deploying the token contracts also with (1) in the constructor, I can not see the token contract code, so I imagine here will be also an error of not passing the appropriate params in the token contracts.